# change of itinerary

Tags: schengen, itineraries

I already have Schengen Visa, however, we added another country which differs from when I applied for visa. Will I have a problem when I enter?

I will be spending more time in the country that issued the visa and I will be both arriving and leaving through the same country that issued the visa.

I actually received it for 15 days since my trip was tourism... is that normal?

Comment: You receive a certain duration based on the itinerary you submitted, your history of using Schengen visa and the mood of consular officers. Anything is possible but 15 days does not seem particularly uncommon.

Comment: Definite duplicate. Please don't double post.